# Waves that are neither stationnary or propagating?

Tags: waves

My question is about understanding better the notion of stationnary waves when the reflection is imperfect.

Consider for the sake of the example an electromagnetic field in free space.

I decompose my field into forward and backward propagating waves as:

$$E(x,t)=E_{\rightarrow}(t-x/c)+E_{\leftarrow}(t+x/c)$$

I use a Fourier decomposition for both propagating directions:

$$E_{\rightarrow}(t-x/c)=\int_0^{+\infty} d \omega \ E^{\omega}_{\rightarrow}(t-x/c)=\int_0^{+\infty} d \omega \ A_{\rightarrow}(\omega) e^{j \omega(t-x/c)}+A^*_{\rightarrow}(\omega) e^{-j \omega(t-x/c)}$$
$$E_{\rightarrow}(t+x/c)=\int_0^{+\infty} d \omega \ E^{\omega}_{\leftarrow}(t+x/c)=\int_0^{+\infty} d \omega \ A_{\leftarrow}(\omega) e^{j \omega(t+x/c)}+A^*_{\leftarrow}(\omega) e^{-j \omega(t+x/c)}$$

Now, let's assume some boundary condition in $x=0$. One way to encode this boundary condition is to define the reflection coefficient:

$$r(\omega)=\frac{A_{\leftarrow}(\omega)}{A_{\rightarrow}(\omega)}$$

This boundary condition "divides by two" the total number of independant mode that exists. What I mean by that is that because of this boundary condition, now we only need to specify the coefficients $A_{\rightarrow}(\omega)$ for $\omega >0$. Before we also needed to specify $A_{\leftarrow}(\omega)$. We have to provide "twice less" information. The independants modes are now:

$$F_{\omega}(x,t)=E^{\omega}_{\rightarrow}(t-x/c)+E^{\omega}_{\leftarrow}(t+x/c)$$

Which gives me in the end:
$$E(x,t)=\int_0^{+\infty} F_{\omega}(x,t) d\omega = \int_0^{+\infty} d \omega e^{j \omega t} A_{\rightarrow}(\omega)(e^{-j \omega x/c}+r(\omega)e^{j \omega x/c})+e^{-j \omega t} A^*_{\rightarrow}(\omega)(e^{j \omega x/c}+r(\omega)e^{-j \omega x/c}) $$

### My question

For the case $r(\omega)=0$ (no reflection) we recognize the resulting wave as being propagating. Indeed we have:

$$E(x,t)=E(t-x/c)=\int_0^{+\infty} d \omega A_{\rightarrow}(\omega) e^{j \omega(t-x/c)}+A^*_{\rightarrow}(\omega) e^{-j \omega(t-x/c)}$$

For $r(\omega)=1$ (perfect reflection), we get:

$$E(x,t)=2 \int_0^{+\infty} d \omega \cos(\omega x/c) \left( e^{j \omega t} A_{\rightarrow}(\omega)  +e^{-j \omega t} A^*_{\rightarrow}( \omega) \right)$$
$$E(x,t)=4 \int_0^{+\infty} d \omega |A_{\rightarrow}(\omega)|\cos(\omega x/c) \cos(\omega t + \phi_{\omega})$$

Where $\phi_{\omega}$ is the phase of $A_{\rightarrow}(\omega)$.

**And here are my questions**:

- Each mode for the perfect reflection is stationnary. But I cannot write $E(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$. So can we really say that the total wave is stationnary ? I guess there is still no energy transfer as each mode is stationnary.
- What about $r(\omega)$ that is neither $1$ or $0$ (in modulus). Is the resulting total field considered as stationnary ? As propagating ? I guess in this case there is still energy transfer (basically if the reflection coefficient is close to $0$ we can expect a net energy flow going to the right for instance). And same question for each mode.

(I know that any wave can be decomposed as a sum of propagating waves, or as a sum of stationnary waves. But this this not what I am asking.)

Comment: you lost me with the "divide by two" thing

Comment: @psitae Thanks for the feedback. I added further explanation. Is that more clear ?

Comment: Yes that's more clear. Next: are you confusing the notions of being stationary and being separable? Can you justify the claim that each perfect reflection is stationary? Can you show how that implies separability?

Comment: @psitae from what I remember the definition of a stationnary wave is exactly the fact that position and time can be decoupled: $E(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$. Maybe my memory is wrong but I don't find easily a source stating clearly the definition.

Comment: I would second the definition of stationary wave, but put the finger on the assumption: why should the total wave function be stationary? If you start out with an arbitrary(?) field, one could build a localized wave packet which is not stationary.